# How can I browserify nodejs's browserify?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I've tried

```
browserify -r browserify
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'brfs'
```

Is there a version of browserify that can work in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Feb 2014 it looks like it works:

```
npm install browserify
browserify -r browserify
```

Outputs the browserified browserify.

Also check out:

http://wzrd.in/bundle/browserify

Answer (score 1):

Use browserify-cdn, it lives at http://wzrd.in

Comment: Nice try! http://wzrd.in/bundle/browserify

`---FLAGRANT SYSTEM ERROR---
Error: "browserify exited with code 1"

code: 1
stderr: Error: module "browserify//github.com/fb55/cqs" not found in require()

dirPath: /tmp/browserify113728-14880-ibdxmm
Get ahold of @jesusabdullah on freenode, twitter or github
with the ENTIRETY of the contents of this message, and he can
try to help you out.

Have a nice day!
`